# Not getting the exact page margin during printout of PDF generated by LaTeX

Tags: margins, geometry

I am using the geometry package:

```
\usepackage[a4paper,margin = 15mm]{geometry}
```

or

```
\usepackage[a4paper,top = 15mm, bottom = 15mm, left = 15mm, right = 15mm]{geometry}
```

But after taking print out of PDF margins are not exactly same.
I observe that whenever I generate the PDF from Texmaker it shows a red box around the title making it 15 mm but not text.
[image]

This red box comes as shown above. It comes as a generate PDF and this red box margin seems to be exact 15 mm which i am giving as option for the `geometry` package.

This is the code which i am using.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin = 15mm]{geometry} %% \usepackage[a4paper,top = 15mm, bottom = 15mm, left = 15mm, right = 15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{asdfghjklqweryuopbkjsvnkjnvklwnkl}}
\author{G. Kataria}
\author{ K. Singh}
\affil{Department of Chemical Engineering, Malaviya National Institute of Technology, Jaipur}
\affil{g.kataria@example.com}
\affil{k.singh@example.org}
\date{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "[TeXmaker] shows red box around title making it 15mm but not text"?

Comment: Do you have "fit to margins" or "fit to papersize" or "fit ?" set for the printer?

Answer (score 3):

The text in the MWE is not suitable for showing the margins. The title is set centered by default. Therefore, the lines do not necessarily need to span the full line width. Since you are using package `geometry`, you can set option `showframe`, which shows you the page layout:

```
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin = 15mm,
  showframe,
]{geometry}
```

Full example with some text:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin = 15mm,
  showframe,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{asdfghjklqweryuopbkjsvnkjnvklwnkl}}
\author{G. Kataria}
\author{ K. Singh}
\affil{Department of Chemical Engineering, Malaviya National Institute of
Technology, Jaipur}
\affil{g.kataria@example.com}
\affil{k.singh@example.org}
\date{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum*[2]\footnote{\lipsum[103]}
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with showframe]

The upper right corner of the text area in the middle should then be 15 mm from the left page border and 15 mm below the top of the page.

When you print with AR, then there are options, which scales the page, thus you need to check them in order to print in actual size.

## Environment abstract

The additional margin of the environment `abstract` comes from environment `quotation`. The following example defines an environment `abstractquotation`, which sets the margin to 0pt. Also it uses `\noindent` for the first paragraph. Environment `abstract` is patched to use `abstractquotation` instead of `quotation`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  margin = 15mm,
  showframe,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newenvironment{abstractquotation}{%
  \list{}{%
    \listparindent 1.5em\relax
    \itemindent\listparindent
    \leftmargin0pt\relax
    \rightmargin\leftmargin
    \parsep 0pt plus 1pt\relax
  }%
  \item\relax
  \noindent\ignorespaces
}{%
  \endlist
}
\patchcmd\abstract{\quotation}{\abstractquotation}{}{%
  \errmessage{\noexpand\abstract could not be patched}%
}
\patchcmd\endabstract{\endquotation}{\endabstractquotation}{}{%
  \errmessage{\noexpand\endabstract could not be patched}%
}

\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{asdfghjklqweryuopbkjsvnkjnvklwnkl}}
\author{G. Kataria}
\author{ K. Singh}
\affil{Department of Chemical Engineering, Malaviya National Institute of
Technology, Jaipur}
\affil{gkataria64@example.com}
\affil{k.singh@example.org}
\date{}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum*[2]\footnote{\lipsum[103]}\par
  \lipsum[3]
\end{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result abstract]

Comment: I just want my whole text start from 15mm margin on both sides what to do for that?

Comment: @gauravkataria Which text? The title is not long enough for that. And the body text has already the margins of 15 mm as you can see in the example given in the answer.

Comment: i am writting a text inside abstract which is not coming under 15 mm margins. I want that text to starts from 15 mm from left and ends to 15mm to right.

Comment: @gauravkataria Answer updated to remove the additional margin of environment `abstract`.